# Weird Issue with JScrollPane - scroll bar not showing up despite use of: setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar

So, in the code below I have a JTextArea on the left side. A JScrollPane on the upper right side that looks fine. Using the same code I also add a JScrollPane on the lower right side, but despite identical code, save the preferred sizes and absolute positioning, the vertical scroll bar does not seem to show up.

I will add a screenshot of the GUI after the code. Thank you in advance for any help resolving this issue.

```
    frame = new JFrame("Title");
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));      
    frame.pack();

    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    frame.setLocation(dim.width/2-frame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-frame.getSize().height/2);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.addKeyListener(this);

    //scroll and text area
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setText("Static Text\n");
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Consolas", 0, 12));      
        textArea.setColumns(50);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width/2, height * 4 / 5));
        scrollPane.setBounds(width/2, 0, width/2, height * 4 / 5);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        inputTextArea = new JTextArea();
        inputTextArea.setText(">");
        inputTextArea.setFont(new Font("Consolas", 0, 12));     
        inputTextArea.setColumns(50);
        inputTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        inputScrollPane = new JScrollPane(inputTextArea);
        inputScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width/2, height / 5));               
        inputScrollPane.setBounds(width/2, height * 4 / 5, width, height);
        inputScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        frame.add(inputScrollPane);
    //map
        mapView = new JTextArea();
        mapView.setFont(new Font("Consolas", 0, 8));        
        mapView.setEditable(false);
        mapView.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width/2, height));
        mapView.setText(state.getCurrentMap().toString());
        mapView.addKeyListener(this);
        mapView.setBounds(0, 0, width/2, height);
        frame.add(mapView);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

[image: As you can see, the lower right JScrollPane is missing the vertical scroll bar]

Comment: Please see edits to code in answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've several significant issues with that code including

- Use of null layouts. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one. This is making your debugging work more difficult, believe me. For that reason you're far better off learning about and using the layout managers. You can find the layout manager tutorial here: [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), and you can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing).
- You're setting the sizes/bounds of your JTextAreas. This prevents them from expanding appropriately when text is added, and will prevent scrollbars from the surrounding JScrollBars from appearing. Set the JTextArea column and row properties instead.
- Adding a KeyListener to your text components. While this is not causing your current error, it is something that should be avoided and will often mess with the function of the component. Much better to use higher level listeners such as DocumentListener or DocumentFilter.

For example, the code below shows how to use simple layouts, text area column and row properties, as well as use of key bindings to capture the user's pressing the enter key, in case this is desired:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LayoutExample extends JPanel {
    private static final int MV_ROWS = 65;
    private static final int MV_COLS = 100;
    private static final int TA_ROWS = 34;
    private static final int TA_COLS = 54;
    private static final int ITA_ROWS = 8;
    private static final Font MV_FONT = new Font("Consolas", 0, 8);
    private static final Font TA_FONT = new Font("Consolas", 0, 12);

    private JTextArea mapView = new JTextArea(MV_ROWS, MV_COLS);
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Static Text\n", TA_ROWS, TA_COLS);
    private JTextArea inputTextArea = new JTextArea(ITA_ROWS, TA_COLS);

    public LayoutExample() {
        mapView.setFont(MV_FONT);
        mapView.setEditable(false);
        mapView.setFocusable(false);
        JScrollPane mvScrollPane = new JScrollPane(mapView);

        textArea.setFont(TA_FONT);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setFocusable(false);
        JScrollPane taScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        taScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        setEnterKeyBindings(inputTextArea);
        inputTextArea.setFont(TA_FONT);
        inputTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        inputTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        JScrollPane itaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(inputTextArea);
        itaScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        rightPanel.add(taScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        rightPanel.add(itaScrollPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        add(mvScrollPane);
        add(rightPanel);

        inputTextArea.setText(">");
    }

    // to capture the "enter" key being pressed without having to use a
    // KeyListener
    private void setEnterKeyBindings(final JTextArea textComponent) {
        // only accept input when this component is focused
        int condition = WHEN_FOCUSED; 
        InputMap inputMap = textComponent.getInputMap(condition);
        ActionMap actionMap = textComponent.getActionMap();

        // only will bind one keystroke -- that for enter key
        KeyStroke enterKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
        inputMap.put(enterKeyStroke, enterKeyStroke.toString());

        // action to take if enter is pressed
        actionMap.put(enterKeyStroke.toString(), new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // get text from input text area, and then clear text
                String text = textComponent.getText();
                textComponent.setText(">");

                // append this text to the upper text area
                textArea.append(text + "\n");

                // TODO: send text elsewhere via chat?
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        LayoutExample mainPanel = new LayoutExample();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: I always check: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html when making a new GUI, but since none of the ones there offered the look I was going for, null layout it was. It's been a about a year since I've coded in java (been doing c and c++ since going to college) and I completely forgot about the column and row properties. I'll edit the code to include that now and let you know if it worked.

Comment: I found my issue. It was but a typo in the line where I set the bounds of the scroll pane. I always default to (x1,y1,x2,y2) instead of (x,y,width,height) for some reason. The scrollbar was there,just outside of the jframe. Thanks for the help.

Comment: And since the JTextArea is inside a JScrollPane, it seems that the number of columns is defaulted to the width of the JScrollPane reguardless if setColumns is used.

Comment: @Deek3117: not if you use appropriate layout managers. Again, if you constrain the text area's size, it *will not expand when it needs to*.

Comment: @Deek3117: not sure what the KeyListener was for, but if it was to try to capture an enter key press, please look at the Key Bindings example above. It is safer than using key listeners.